# how rsp is decremented in prologue on a X86-64 architecture

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly, function-calls

I am trying to understand  how functions are called in C. When I disassemble this code (gcc - gdb; I am on Linux with an i5-3320M) to get the prologue of function `toto`:

```
void nop(){return ;}

void toto(int i, int j)
{
return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i = 1;
  int* pt;
  i = 0;
}
```

I get the prologue:

```
   0x0000000000400523 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400524 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400527 <+4>: sub    $0x8,%rsp
```

Here I don't understand why `rsp` is decremented by 8 as I do not use a local variable in `toto`. Moreover, if I do use a local variable:

```
void toto(int i, int j)
{
    int i=1
    return;
}
```

I get the following prologue:

```
   0x0000000000400523 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400524 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400527 <+4>: sub    $0x18,%rsp
```

And here I don't understand why `rsp` is decremented by 0x18 (24 bytes). I would expect something like 16 bytes because I already have a mysterious offset of 8, plus I need 4 bytes for the int. But my architecture is 64 bit, a word in the stack can't be less than 8 bytes so 8+8 = 16.

Comment: The `sub 8` is obvious, since you have two 4-byte variables that are pushed into the stack before the function is called (the function arguments `i` and `j`).

Comment: @barakmanos: No! In 64-bit mode the first arguments are passed in registers.

Comment: @GerardBouchar: I can't reproduce your assembly (GCC 4.7.2-5 at Debian Wheezy). Please post your steps to get that assembly (full command lines).

Answer (score 3):

[The x86_64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) requires that upon entering a function, `%rsp` be always a multiple of 16. <s>Thus, after `push %rbp`, `%rsp` must be subtracted a value like 0x8, 0x18, 0x28 etc.</s>

UPDATE. Sorry everyone who upvoted this, I deceived you. It can be easily seen that each `push %rbp%` is always paired with a `call` or `callq` which gives 0x10 bytes, thus the extra value subtracted from `%rsp` must be multiple of 0x10 as well.

As to your first question, you must be compiling without optimization. With optimization, all your functions collapse to mere `repz retq`.